# Role.IsUserInRole

Tags: c#, asp.net, roles

I am adding a user to a role as follows (note that I run the code shown below on my machine):

```
    Roles.AddUserToRole(oMU.UserName, "Role1");
```

With the following code I check to see if the user is in the role:

```
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(txtUserName.Text.Trim(), "Role1"))
```

and the user is indeed in the role.

I run the following to check if the current logged in user is in Role1 but it fails to enter the if statement - WHY? :

```
     if (User.IsUserInRole("Role1"))
     {
       // does not enter this code 
     }
```

Comment: Doesn't this just mean that whatever is in `User.Identity.Name` is not equal to what is in `txtUserName.Text.Trim()`?  You should check those values.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call `Roles.IsUserInRole("Role1")`

as soon as user is assigned to a role like this -

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(oMU.UserName, "Role1");
```

### Why?

**IPrincipal object** is injected to `HttpContext.Current.User` on  `Application_AuthenticateRequest` only.

Therefore, you'll have to wait for next request in order to access `Roles.IsUserInRole("Role1")`.

### Updated

Make sure `cacheRolesInCookie` is set to false, because it has some issues.

```
<roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false" 
   defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      ....
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Thanks Win. My whole goal is to register a user and then heck by way of User.IsInRole but it seems that the user is not in the role. They are in a seperate request. Hope this make sense.

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112536/roles-issue-with-user-isinrole where I explain it better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be `User.IsInRole` instead of `Roles.IsUserInRole`, or specifically specify the username as a parameter by passing `Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name,"Role1")`

Roles.IsUserInRole, with one parameter, calls GetCurrentUser() for the username which will pull it from the CurrentPrincipal.  It sounds like it your currently logged in user is different from that on the current principal.

Comment: This is two different ways of doing the same thing. The Roles.IsUserInRole that takes just one string argument checks if the current User (HttpContext.User, the same one from User.IsInRole) is in the role specified in the strong.

Comment: Thanks Nate. I am creating a register form where I assign the user to a role. When the user signs in, I check if they are part of the Role by using User.IsInRole. Why does this not work.

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16112536/roles-issue-with-user-isinrole where I explain it better. Thanks