# Roles - Issue with User.IsInRole

Tags: asp.net, role

I have a register page where the user is assigned to a role as follows once the user clicks on the submit button:

```
    MembershipUser oMU;

    if (!(Roles.RoleExists("Stream")))
    {
        Roles.CreateRole("Stream");
    }

    oMU = Membership.CreateUser(txtUserName.Text.Trim(), txtPassword.Text.Trim(), txtEmail.Text.Trim());

    Membership.UpdateUser(oMU);

    Roles.AddUserToRole(oMU.UserName, "Stream");
```

When the user goes to a login screen, I  have the following:

When the user logs in, I need to make sure that they indeed are part of that role:

```
    if (User.IsInRole("Stream"))
    {

    }
```

but it never goes into the User.IsInRole block. What do I need to do in order to have the user who registered be part of the Role such that it works with User.IsInRole.

Note that I have a folder as such so I need them to be part of the Streaming Role:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <configuration>
   <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
        <allow roles="Stream" />           
    </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `<allow roles="Stream" />` above `<deny users="*" />`. Otherwise, all users will be denied.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow roles="Stream" />    
        <deny users="*" />       
    </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Make sure to you have membership and RoleManager in web.config**

Here is the sample -

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="XXXXXSqlConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="XXXXX"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="XXXXXSqlConnection" applicationName="XXXXX"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question being asked (if I'm readng the question right).  Although I agree that the OP should do this.

Comment: Yes, thanks Win. But why does it not even get to  if (User.IsInRole("Stream"))
    {

    }

Comment: Could you make sure to set **RoleManager**'s ***cacheRolesInCookie*** is set to ***false*** in web.config?

Comment: I have not. I am assuming I should do this in my root web.config?

Comment: Theoretically you should override the default one with your own, because you might not know what is inside your hosting server's web.config and machine.config. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi Win,  I added the false to the cache but still getting same issue.

Comment: Which event is `if (User.IsInRole("Stream")) { }` located in? Please add the full event code.

Comment: Hi Win - it is in here:  protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        if (User.IsInRole("Stream"))
        {
            const string url = "~/StreamingVideo/WatchLive/SmartWaterStream.aspx";
            Response.Redirect(url);
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.Text = "Wrong UserName/Pwd Combination";
        }

Comment: Like I said in your other question - ***IPrincipal object is injected to HttpContext.Current.User on Application_AuthenticateRequest only***. Therefore, inside ***btnLogin_Click*** method, you need to explicitly call methods with username parameter - ***Roles.IsUserInRole(Username, "Stream")***.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **HttpContext** to get current login user:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Stream"))
{

}
```